# При большом количестве Get запросов приложение уходить в фон

Tags: android, многопоточность, retrofit2

При большом количестве запросов ,Retrofit,со временем , перестает получать ответы,а приложение уходить фон.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit2 = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                .baseUrl("https://...")
                .addConverterFactory(PostAdapter.FACTORY)
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

Запрос

```
  for(int i=0;i<listUrl.size();i++)
            NetworkClient.getPostService().getData(HttpUrl.parse("https://example.com"+listUrl.get(i)))
                    .enqueue(new Callback<Page>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<Page> call, Response<Page> response) {
                            AppDatabase
                                    .getInstance(App.getAppContext())
                                    .getRepoDao()
                                    .insert( new Ogloszenia(response.body().content));


                        }
```

Как исправить или хотя бы, что б выбрасывал exception.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш метод в один момент времени создает n количество запросов в сеть. Можете отказаться от асинхронного выполнения запросов.

Создайте свой поток в котором в цикле retrofit будет отправлять запрос и принимать ответ - синхронно, запрос отправляется после выполнения предыдущего..

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests